# Linux server blocking outgoing port 443 connections, unsure why

Tags: linux, linux-networking

I have an older CentOS server that will not let me access any SSL websites from it (which I need, to use Composer). IPTables seems fine and when I run it I get this:

iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT

Is there any other program that might be doing this? I can't spot any firewall running.

openssl s_client -connect getcomposer.org:443

CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = DE, L = Berlin, O = Packagist Conductors UG (haftungsbeschr\C3\A4nkt), CN = getcomposer.org

### verify return:1

Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=DE/L=Berlin/O=Packagist Conductors UG (haftungsbeschr\xC3\xA4nkt)/CN=getcomposer.org
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA

### i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Global Root CA

Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFNDCCBBygAwIBAgIQDX53f8WI3kAqaxL0dihiYTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBN
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMScwJQYDVQQDEx5E
aWdpQ2VydCBTSEEyIFNlY3VyZSBTZXJ2ZXIgQ0EwHhcNMTcwNzEyMDAwMDAwWhcN
MjAwODI1MTIwMDAwWjBwMQswCQYDVQQGEwJERTEPMA0GA1UEBxMGQmVybGluMTYw
NAYDVQQKDC1QYWNrYWdpc3QgQ29uZHVjdG9ycyBVRyAoaGFmdHVuZ3NiZXNjaHLD
pG5rdCkxGDAWBgNVBAMTD2dldGNvbXBvc2VyLm9yZzCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEB
BQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAM4BEP87WpGJOrEwV8mbpIO+qaEDMxgj0wZKPslnKgqf
l+kTDOsvwUO+d5hQESg87/9BxnCvwZqzErqxBiEP46g8nZMICl16xeiqE61aiMQj
eYEr8R2YFGVG0yZ5WReMCpiQkXxvPSxkzaPukAKzqYjbHjqTMoYJMtFPz73c+0Te
eUA4bENz7RhLC+86tlrZKxuXwx1o6KcFBFBmIuOl4vspP6AIJd+pzqctEZer5nnm
3xJ4BVcLDCtiqbPgFF62Lib+x6s0iCuTTYS2klD5GSvb8shSJTIrLLrQDeq0QtjZ
f/0UXGQCbxxErs/FeoQTYwAbLN2I4OPy3C+pKrqD4isCAwEAAaOCAeswggHnMB8G
A1UdIwQYMBaAFA+AYRyCMWHVLyjnjUY4tCzhxtniMB0GA1UdDgQWBBRud+hiM13r
jtLi7Xlmj1IjavZzGDAvBgNVHREEKDAmgg9nZXRjb21wb3Nlci5vcmeCE3d3dy5n
ZXRjb21wb3Nlci5vcmcwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgWgMB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUF
BwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjBrBgNVHR8EZDBiMC+gLaArhilodHRwOi8vY3JsMy5kaWdp
Y2VydC5jb20vc3NjYS1zaGEyLWcxLmNybDAvoC2gK4YpaHR0cDovL2NybDQuZGln
aWNlcnQuY29tL3NzY2Etc2hhMi1nMS5jcmwwTAYDVR0gBEUwQzA3BglghkgBhv1s
AQEwKjAoBggrBgEFBQcCARYcaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tL0NQUzAI
BgZngQwBAgIwfAYIKwYBBQUHAQEEcDBuMCQGCCsGAQUFBzABhhhodHRwOi8vb2Nz
cC5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20wRgYIKwYBBQUHMAKGOmh0dHA6Ly9jYWNlcnRzLmRpZ2lj
ZXJ0LmNvbS9EaWdpQ2VydFNIQTJTZWN1cmVTZXJ2ZXJDQS5jcnQwDAYDVR0TAQH/
BAIwADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAIuKx9nWhwJ2tOj8g4TkCm5r56XcQ2iLt
lMuYNzzc84lEW6RT8HGW+WQansgjpmvDZpmEs9RzSR85ZvP18Ua/048nSzBY4AQH
+IiAcVwML33dbamYDaQA8qL1Dy0xd+x2Op22P/ontmvHm4pJVrX/PYNFkJ1dWp/C
5Nvs9BcQcjRp3GljXla0S56hcI+kOFBL/kgv2TfLIv08sRqNcJylXQGjOVztZY72
a/BKU8kDgnU9yeJop6N4Mi8qbP2B8fgmxUjEjbFdYb9HNorzlMNuUbBy9nPqSUoF
3q9KZRQz99nbHGaY6S/90mS7zN4OAtdmiaf4Kpn0oRa+C8upTAXpRw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=DE/L=Berlin/O=Packagist Conductors UG (haftungsbeschr\xC3\xA4nkt)/CN=getcomposer.org

### issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA

No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512

### Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits

### SSL handshake has read 3190 bytes and written 415 bytes

New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: C8BA5ADD002CDF3BC52D3649896E2EDE4D17F8D1532C153F31804455DC058E65
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: DFBB5C35342517FF6D2B216B7470B7AF3204B9F107993E3561535D64E71B78099B6A74DC95BF42E1D2C5DF1B97012A4A
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 86400 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 37 95 6f ff f6 4b 47 09-43 b0 94 ea 3d 39 83 d1   7.o..KG.C...=9..
    0010 - ee a7 89 41 04 c2 c2 d5-66 ab 4b 57 c2 8b 3a 4c   ...A....f.KW..:L
    0020 - 6b 82 e3 61 cf 44 db 4b-ac eb a8 3e ab db 4c 94   k..a.D.K...>..L.
    0030 - fc 23 7a 6c a4 53 eb ec-ad a1 83 81 59 1a d5 25   .#zl.S......Y..%
    0040 - bc 2a d3 15 e1 fa aa 48-35 96 1b 5a 21 fe c5 15   .*.....H5..Z!...
    0050 - 63 af 8a 7c 76 ef 12 24-4e 5b 3c 5d 0a e4 d7 54   c..|v..$N[<]...T
    0060 - e0 7e ac f9 2f 32 b0 4a-5a ec 1b 03 d6 52 d6 9d   .~../2.JZ....R..
    0070 - 20 e0 f3 75 bc 2c 80 40-7e fb 26 ef 84 84 fb 64    ..u.,.@~.&....d
    0080 - f7 d2 fc 6b 61 f6 b9 c8-20 15 41 20 77 bc 89 a0   ...ka... .A w...
    0090 - 9f 7a e4 ab bf 30 bd 97-e3 54 50 d3 55 47 91 bd   .z...0...TP.UG..
    00a0 - aa 54 20 81 62 83 e2 60-a8 54 71 11 11 8c d5 92   .T .b..`.Tq.....

```
Start Time: 1530325185
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
```

### Verify return code: 0 (ok)

closed

Comment: How old of an OS? Does it support modern TLS protocols and ciphers? Can you telnet to 443 and see if it makes a connection

Comment: Not insanely old, maybe 4 years. No clue on the TLS question - I am not smart on this stuff. Just telnetted though and nothing, just hands there.

Comment: Can you ping the requested server or even access it at port 80 for example?

Comment: Yep, no problem pinging them. I did realize that I *am* able to telnet to port 443 of another server I own at a difference server place, so maybe this isn't the issue. But I can't connect to google or getcomposer.org

Comment: It does seem like it's an SSL problem in some way, no clue how to fix though. I'm almost on the most recent version of OpenSSL

Comment: Is it enforcing SELinux? And from what context does composer execute? Is it different if you start it from your own shell?

Comment: user188737 thank you for your thoughtful questions. I don't know what any of them mean

Comment: You can try with 'openssl s_client -connect your-host:443' to see if it tells you something meaningful or just keeps hanging.

Comment: Tonioc - it did indeed give me info (I thought initially no because it hung so long), I'm going to paste it in the questions since it's so much